# PHP paypal express checkout integration always charging 1GBP

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, paypal

This is my first time trying to integrate paypal express checkout into a plugin so bear with me.

My aim is simple, I have a question form, when a user clicks on submit, they are taken to Paypal where they pay a fixed amount (let's say 0.1 USD), on successful payment they are sent back to the question form where their question is submitted. i.e The user has to pay to submit a question.

I went through the paypal integration wizard for Paypal Express, however it is trying to get me to set up a cart, billing, confirm and review page which is total overkill for what I'm trying to do.

Here is the current code I have. Here is my question form:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['Payment_Amount'] = "0.1";
?>

<div id="askme">
    <form id="newask" name="newask" method="post" action="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ); ?>expresscheckout.php">

        <label for="question" id="questionLabel"><?php _e('Your video question link:', 'askme-plugin'); ?></label><br />
        <input type="text" id="question" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="question" />

        <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Pay and Submit Your Question" tabindex="6" id="submit" name="submit" /></p>

        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" id="post_type" value="askme" />
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="post" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>

    </form>
</div>
```

Then in expresscheckout.php I have:

```
<?php

require_once ("paypalfunctions.php");

$paymentAmount = $_SESSION["Payment_Amount"];
$currencyCodeType = "USD";
$paymentType = "Sale";


$returnURL = "http://www.jamespaynedrums.com/ask-a-question/ask-a-question-2?question_confirm=1";

$cancelURL = "http://www.jamespaynedrums.com/ask-a-question/ask-a-question-2?question_cancel=1";

//'------------------------------------
//' Calls the SetExpressCheckout API call
//'
//' The CallShortcutExpressCheckout function is defined in the file PayPalFunctions.php,
//' it is included at the top of this file.
//'-------------------------------------------------
$resArray = CallShortcutExpressCheckout ($paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL);
$ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
if($ack=="SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING")
{
    RedirectToPayPal ( $resArray["TOKEN"] );
} 
else  
{
//Display a user friendly Error on the page using any of the following error information returned by PayPal
$ErrorCode = urldecode($resArray["L_ERRORCODE0"]);
$ErrorShortMsg = urldecode($resArray["L_SHORTMESSAGE0"]);
$ErrorLongMsg = urldecode($resArray["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]);
$ErrorSeverityCode = urldecode($resArray["L_SEVERITYCODE0"]);

echo "SetExpressCheckout API call failed. ";
echo "Detailed Error Message: " . $ErrorLongMsg;
echo "Short Error Message: " . $ErrorShortMsg;
echo "Error Code: " . $ErrorCode;
echo "Error Severity Code: " . $ErrorSeverityCode;
}
?>
```

and finally in paypalfunctions.php (required in expresscheckout.php) I have (with API creds blocked out)

```
<?php
/********************************************
PayPal API Module

Defines all the global variables and the wrapper functions 
********************************************/
$PROXY_HOST = '127.0.0.1';
$PROXY_PORT = '808';

$SandboxFlag = false;

//'------------------------------------
//' PayPal API Credentials
//' Replace <API_USERNAME> with your API Username
//' Replace <API_PASSWORD> with your API Password
//' Replace <API_SIGNATURE> with your Signature
//'------------------------------------
$API_UserName="**BLANKED OUT**";
$API_Password="**BLANKED OUT**";
$API_Signature="**BLANKED OUT**";

// BN Code  is only applicable for partners
$sBNCode = "PP-ECWizard";


/*  
' Define the PayPal Redirect URLs.  
'   This is the URL that the buyer is first sent to do authorize payment with their paypal account
'   change the URL depending if you are testing on the sandbox or the live PayPal site
'
' For the sandbox, the URL is       https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=
' For the live site, the URL is        https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=
*/

if ($SandboxFlag == true) 
{
    $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";
    $PAYPAL_URL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=";
}
else
{
    $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
    $PAYPAL_URL = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=";
}

$USE_PROXY = false;
$version="93";

if (session_id() == "") 
    session_start();

/* An express checkout transaction starts with a token, that
   identifies to PayPal your transaction
   In this example, when the script sees a token, the script
   knows that the buyer has already authorized payment through
   paypal.  If no token was found, the action is to send the buyer
   to PayPal to first authorize payment
   */

/*   
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the SetExpressCheckout API Call.
' Inputs:  
'       paymentAmount:      Total value of the shopping cart
'       currencyCodeType:   Currency code value the PayPal API
'       paymentType:        paymentType has to be one of the following values: Sale or Order or Authorization
'       returnURL:          the page where buyers return to after they are done with the payment review on PayPal
'       cancelURL:          the page where buyers return to when they cancel the payment review on PayPal
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
*/
function CallShortcutExpressCheckout( $paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL) 
{
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Construct the parameter string that describes the SetExpressCheckout API call in the shortcut implementation

    $nvpstr="&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=". $paymentAmount;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=" . $paymentType;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&RETURNURL=" . $returnURL;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CANCELURL=" . $cancelURL;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCodeType;

    $_SESSION["currencyCodeType"] = $currencyCodeType;    
    $_SESSION["PaymentType"] = $paymentType;

    //'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    //' Make the API call to PayPal
    //' If the API call succeded, then redirect the buyer to PayPal to begin to authorize payment.  
    //' If an error occured, show the resulting errors
    //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $resArray=hash_call("SetExpressCheckout", $nvpstr);
    $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
    if($ack=="SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING")
    {
        $token = urldecode($resArray["TOKEN"]);
        $_SESSION['TOKEN']=$token;
    }

    return $resArray;
}

/*   
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the SetExpressCheckout API Call.
' Inputs:  
'       paymentAmount:      Total value of the shopping cart
'       currencyCodeType:   Currency code value the PayPal API
'       paymentType:        paymentType has to be one of the following values: Sale or Order or Authorization
'       returnURL:          the page where buyers return to after they are done with the payment review on PayPal
'       cancelURL:          the page where buyers return to when they cancel the payment review on PayPal
'       shipToName:     the Ship to name entered on the merchant's site
'       shipToStreet:       the Ship to Street entered on the merchant's site
'       shipToCity:         the Ship to City entered on the merchant's site
'       shipToState:        the Ship to State entered on the merchant's site
'       shipToCountryCode:  the Code for Ship to Country entered on the merchant's site
'       shipToZip:          the Ship to ZipCode entered on the merchant's site
'       shipToStreet2:      the Ship to Street2 entered on the merchant's site
'       phoneNum:           the phoneNum  entered on the merchant's site
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
*/
function CallMarkExpressCheckout( $paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, 
                                  $cancelURL, $shipToName, $shipToStreet, $shipToCity, $shipToState,
                                  $shipToCountryCode, $shipToZip, $shipToStreet2, $phoneNum
                                ) 
{
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Construct the parameter string that describes the SetExpressCheckout API call in the shortcut implementation

    $nvpstr="&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=". $paymentAmount;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=" . $paymentType;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&RETURNURL=" . $returnURL;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CANCELURL=" . $cancelURL;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCodeType;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&ADDROVERRIDE=1";
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME=" . $shipToName;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET=" . $shipToStreet;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2=" . $shipToStreet2;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY=" . $shipToCity;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE=" . $shipToState;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=" . $shipToCountryCode;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP=" . $shipToZip;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM=" . $phoneNum;

    $_SESSION["currencyCodeType"] = $currencyCodeType;    
    $_SESSION["PaymentType"] = $paymentType;

    //'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    //' Make the API call to PayPal
    //' If the API call succeded, then redirect the buyer to PayPal to begin to authorize payment.  
    //' If an error occured, show the resulting errors
    //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $resArray=hash_call("SetExpressCheckout", $nvpstr);
    $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
    if($ack=="SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING")
    {
        $token = urldecode($resArray["TOKEN"]);
        $_SESSION['TOKEN']=$token;
    }

    return $resArray;
}

/*
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the GetExpressCheckoutDetails API Call.
'
' Inputs:  
'       None
' Returns: 
'       The NVP Collection object of the GetExpressCheckoutDetails Call Response.
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
function GetShippingDetails( $token )
{
    //'--------------------------------------------------------------
    //' At this point, the buyer has completed authorizing the payment
    //' at PayPal.  The function will call PayPal to obtain the details
    //' of the authorization, incuding any shipping information of the
    //' buyer.  Remember, the authorization is not a completed transaction
    //' at this state - the buyer still needs an additional step to finalize
    //' the transaction
    //'--------------------------------------------------------------

    //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //' Build a second API request to PayPal, using the token as the
    //'  ID to get the details on the payment authorization
    //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $nvpstr="&TOKEN=" . $token;

    //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //' Make the API call and store the results in an array.  
    //' If the call was a success, show the authorization details, and provide
    //'     an action to complete the payment.  
    //' If failed, show the error
    //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $resArray=hash_call("GetExpressCheckoutDetails",$nvpstr);
    $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
    if($ack == "SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING")
    {   
        $_SESSION['payer_id'] = $resArray['PAYERID'];
    } 
    return $resArray;
}

/*
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the GetExpressCheckoutDetails API Call.
'
' Inputs:  
'       sBNCode:    The BN code used by PayPal to track the transactions from a given shopping cart.
' Returns: 
'       The NVP Collection object of the GetExpressCheckoutDetails Call Response.
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
*/
function ConfirmPayment( $FinalPaymentAmt )
{
    /* Gather the information to make the final call to
       finalize the PayPal payment.  The variable nvpstr
       holds the name value pairs
       */


    //Format the other parameters that were stored in the session from the previous calls   
    $token              = urlencode($_SESSION['TOKEN']);
    $paymentType        = urlencode($_SESSION['PaymentType']);
    $currencyCodeType   = urlencode($_SESSION['currencyCodeType']);
    $payerID            = urlencode($_SESSION['payer_id']);

    $serverName         = urlencode($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

    $nvpstr  = '&TOKEN=' . $token . '&PAYERID=' . $payerID . '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=' . $paymentType . '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=' . $FinalPaymentAmt;
    $nvpstr .= '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=' . $currencyCodeType . '&IPADDRESS=' . $serverName; 

     /* Make the call to PayPal to finalize payment
        If an error occured, show the resulting errors
        */
    $resArray=hash_call("DoExpressCheckoutPayment",$nvpstr);

    /* Display the API response back to the browser.
       If the response from PayPal was a success, display the response parameters'
       If the response was an error, display the errors received using APIError.php.
       */
    $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);

    return $resArray;
}

/*
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose:  This function makes a DoDirectPayment API call
'
' Inputs:  
'       paymentType:        paymentType has to be one of the following values: Sale or Order or Authorization
'       paymentAmount:      total value of the shopping cart
'       currencyCode:       currency code value the PayPal API
'       firstName:          first name as it appears on credit card
'       lastName:           last name as it appears on credit card
'       street:             buyer's street address line as it appears on credit card
'       city:               buyer's city
'       state:              buyer's state
'       countryCode:        buyer's country code
'       zip:                buyer's zip
'       creditCardType:     buyer's credit card type (i.e. Visa, MasterCard ... )
'       creditCardNumber:   buyers credit card number without any spaces, dashes or any other characters
'       expDate:            credit card expiration date
'       cvv2:               Card Verification Value 
'       
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'       
' Returns: 
'       The NVP Collection object of the DoDirectPayment Call Response.
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
*/


function DirectPayment( $paymentType, $paymentAmount, $creditCardType, $creditCardNumber,
                        $expDate, $cvv2, $firstName, $lastName, $street, $city, $state, $zip, 
                        $countryCode, $currencyCode )
{
    //Construct the parameter string that describes DoDirectPayment
    $nvpstr = "&AMT=" . $paymentAmount;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCode;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTACTION=" . $paymentType;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CREDITCARDTYPE=" . $creditCardType;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&ACCT=" . $creditCardNumber;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&EXPDATE=" . $expDate;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CVV2=" . $cvv2;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&FIRSTNAME=" . $firstName;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&LASTNAME=" . $lastName;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&STREET=" . $street;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CITY=" . $city;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&STATE=" . $state;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&COUNTRYCODE=" . $countryCode;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&IPADDRESS=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $resArray=hash_call("DoDirectPayment", $nvpstr);

    return $resArray;
}


/**
  '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  * hash_call: Function to perform the API call to PayPal using API signature
  * @methodName is name of API  method.
  * @nvpStr is nvp string.
  * returns an associtive array containing the response from the server.
  '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
function hash_call($methodName,$nvpStr)
{
    //declaring of global variables
    global $API_Endpoint, $version, $API_UserName, $API_Password, $API_Signature;
    global $USE_PROXY, $PROXY_HOST, $PROXY_PORT;
    global $gv_ApiErrorURL;
    global $sBNCode;

    //setting the curl parameters.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$API_Endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    //turning off the server and peer verification(TrustManager Concept).
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    //if USE_PROXY constant set to TRUE in Constants.php, then only proxy will be enabled.
   //Set proxy name to PROXY_HOST and port number to PROXY_PORT in constants.php 
    if($USE_PROXY)
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $PROXY_HOST. ":" . $PROXY_PORT); 

    //NVPRequest for submitting to server
    $nvpreq="METHOD=" . urlencode($methodName) . "&VERSION=" . urlencode($version) . "&PWD=" . urlencode($API_Password) . "&USER=" . urlencode($API_UserName) . "&SIGNATURE=" . urlencode($API_Signature) . $nvpStr . "&BUTTONSOURCE=" . urlencode($sBNCode);

    //setting the nvpreq as POST FIELD to curl
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

    //getting response from server
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    //convrting NVPResponse to an Associative Array
    $nvpResArray=deformatNVP($response);
    $nvpReqArray=deformatNVP($nvpreq);
    $_SESSION['nvpReqArray']=$nvpReqArray;

    if (curl_errno($ch)) 
    {
        // moving to display page to display curl errors
          $_SESSION['curl_error_no']=curl_errno($ch) ;
          $_SESSION['curl_error_msg']=curl_error($ch);

          //Execute the Error handling module to display errors. 
    } 
    else 
    {
         //closing the curl
        curl_close($ch);
    }

    return $nvpResArray;
}

/*'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Purpose: Redirects to PayPal.com site.
 Inputs:  NVP string.
 Returns: 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
function RedirectToPayPal ( $token )
{
    global $PAYPAL_URL;

    // Redirect to paypal.com here
    $payPalURL = $PAYPAL_URL . $token;
    header("Location: ".$payPalURL);
    exit;
}


/*'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * This function will take NVPString and convert it to an Associative Array and it will decode the response.
  * It is usefull to search for a particular key and displaying arrays.
  * @nvpstr is NVPString.
  * @nvpArray is Associative Array.
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  */
function deformatNVP($nvpstr)
{
    $intial=0;
    $nvpArray = array();

    while(strlen($nvpstr))
    {
        //postion of Key
        $keypos= strpos($nvpstr,'=');
        //position of value
        $valuepos = strpos($nvpstr,'&') ? strpos($nvpstr,'&'): strlen($nvpstr);

        /*getting the Key and Value values and storing in a Associative Array*/
        $keyval=substr($nvpstr,$intial,$keypos);
        $valval=substr($nvpstr,$keypos+1,$valuepos-$keypos-1);
        //decoding the respose
        $nvpArray[urldecode($keyval)] =urldecode( $valval);
        $nvpstr=substr($nvpstr,$valuepos+1,strlen($nvpstr));
     }
    return $nvpArray;
}

?>
```

Currently, when I click on my form submit button, I am taken to paypal, I log in and it is trying to charge me 1GBP - not 0.1USD.

Also worth mentioning that this is a wordpress plugin, and at the top of my file containing the form (askme.php) I have the following code:

```
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');

function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}

function myEndSession() {
    session_destroy ();
}
```

Comment: You should try and narrow down this question to the core problem. There is a lot of code here, developery might not want to read it all. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Question: Where do you call ConfirmPayment() ? It appears that the parameter for the amount is passed in there, but I can not find a call.

Comment: Hi @ArSeN thanks for the comment. I just included the main paypal files for reference, but I'm assuming that someone with experience integrating paypal would be able to navigate these files. Still, apologies for the amount of code. I'm not 100% sure what you mean by calling ConfirmPayment() - any other help you can provide?